# Creating a column name dacade from year

Tags: r, datetime, formatting

Suppose you have a variable year(which is column variable) in a data frame. If we want to create/add a new variable name decade in the same data frame, where if the years are in between 1960 to 1969, the label of decade variable would be sixty and so on. Probably it's not that difficult, but I am new about this type of data formatting.

Comment: What format is your column in? And does it have to be the character "sixty" or may it be "60s"? And do you have different centuries? And if so, do you want to distinguish decades (2020s and 1920s)? Please add some information on your data and requirements and probably a piece of code where you tried it yourself.

Comment: @MartinWettstein Don't have any different centuries. The year are in between 1950 to now. I would like to know in both way "sixty" and "60s" if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you only have years in the XX. century, first you need to make a character variable that stores your decade names:

```
decades <- c("10s", "20s", "30s", "40s", "50s", "60s", "70s", "80s", "90s")
```

Or you get the same result with

```
decades <- paste(1:9 * 10, "s", sep = "")
```

Then

```
df$decades <- decades[(df$year - 1900) %/% 10]
```

Where `%/%` is the quotient, and with the help of that you can change your solution according to your needs

Comment: Error: Assigned data `decades[(df$year - 1900)%/%10]` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 230 rows.
x Assigned data has 0 rows.

Comment: I can see that you have years after the XX. century, so ```(df$year - 1900) %/% 10``` this will be 11 or more, and the decade variable I defined has only 9 elements. You need to change ```1900``` to ```1950``` if that's your earliest date and make a decades vector from the 50s until 20s (which corresponds to 2020s)

Comment: maybe your data frame is not called ```df``` ? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom collection of labels for specific values and loop over the data.

```
df = data.frame(column = c(1965,1958,1971,1980,1989))

keys = list(list(1950,1959,"fifties"),
            list(1960,1969,"sixties"),
            list(1970,1979,"seventies"),
            list(1980,1989,"eighties"),
            list(1990,1999,"nineties"))
df$Label = NA
for(k in keys){
  df$Label[df$column >= k[[1]] & df$column <= k[[2]]]=k[[3]]
}
```

The output of this little program is:

```
> df
  column     Label
1   1965   sixties
2   1958   fifties
3   1971 seventies
4   1980  eighties
5   1989  eighties
```

You can see that it would be quite easy to extend and adapt it to your exact problem.